# How to fix style attribute not found in Xamarin Project

Tags: android, xamarin

There are two XML files referencing color in the Xamarin project with Visual Studio:

Styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->  
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
 </style>  
  <style name="CustomButton" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">    
     <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/btn_normal</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
  <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" /> 
 </resources>
```

And:

colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#DD5706</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1B3147</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#8167E6</color>    
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="darkwhite">#EFFFFE</color>
    <color name="transparent">#00ffff</color>
    <color name="semitransparent">#880000</color>
    <color name="orange">#ff8800</color>
    <color name="light_orange">#e27d18</color>
    <color name="light_blue">#1E90FF</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="menuButtonColor">#ea8e44</color>
    <color name="btn_normal">#ea8e44</color>
    <color name="pressed_color">#e27d18</color>
    <color name="default_color">#f8f1e7</color>
    <color name="selected">#f8dcd3</color>
  </resources>
```

When I do the build I get errors like this:

style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.robo.alkemit:attr/colorPrimary)' not found

But both files are in the Resources/values folder (and have been for a long time).

Thanks.

Comment: I did a test, but I couldn't reproduce this problem. But you can try to delete the obj/ bin folders, then restart VS, and rebuild it.

Comment: Did just that, many times.

Comment: You can try to create a new demo and copy your code to the new one, then try again.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that. There's a lot of code.

Comment: Hi @Ron, have you resolved your problem?

Comment: Yes and it was caused by the dumbest of reasons: resource.designer.cs was, somehow, not in the project. It was before, but then it wasn't. Once I added it in the app compiled.